# Как доказать равенство сочетаний?

Tags: теория-вероятностей

Нужно доказать равенство:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал расписать через факториалы, подобавлять разные части, ни к чему не привело.

Comment: а по-русски можно?

Comment: Приведите ваши выкладки. Что вы сделали? Где остановились? Почему?

Comment: @Zhihar доказать уравнение это

Comment: @Aeros, вы начинаете, мы вам помогаем. Только так.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

задача для 2 класса, когда прошли умножение и раскрытие скобок фонтанчиком

стыдно должно быть :)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: признавайтесь, это ведь компьютерная алгебра выкладки делала? Ни за что не поверю что человек обошелся без сокращения одинаковых множителей в равенстве.

Comment: И при этом быстро!

Comment: эти выкладки я делал в Word используя записанную в самом начале формулу для кол-ва сочетаний (C(m,n)), предпоследний этап только на бумажке расписал (где 4 суммы по 3 множителя), потому что в ворде в редакторе формул набивать тяжело, а уж понять, что n^3 + 6n^2 + 11n + 6 - это (n+1)(n+2)(n+3) не так и сложно

Comment: Снимаю шляпу. :)